# Axiom of Regularity implies $X$ has an $\epsilon_x$-minimal element (wrong proof).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove the next equivalence:

(1) Axiom or Regularity

(2) If $X$ is a non-empty set, $X$ has an $\epsilon_x$-minimal element. This means, There exists a $z \in x$ such that $\lnot (x \in_x z )$ for all $x \in X.$

I got (1) $\rightarrow$ (2) wrong in an exam.

Because I didn't prove that "the $z$ existed." I am not being able to understand this observation, and so, I don't know how to correct this proof, or taking it into the right direction. So here's my attempt:

The Axiom of Regularity says: Let $A$ be a set, with $A \neq \emptyset $.  There exists an $a \in X$ such that, if $b \in a$, then $b$ is not in $A$.

**Proof**. As $X$ is not empty, there exists a $z\in X$. If $z\in X, $ and for some $x$, $x\in X$ then, by the Axiom of Regularity, $x \notin_x z.$
So, $\lnot(x \in_x z).$

Comment: What does "$\in_x$" mean?

Comment: It means $\in$ restricted to the set $x$

Comment: Then you should write "$\in_X$" instead of "$\in_x$" (and usually we'd just write "$\in$," since we don't treat different membership relations simultaneously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second-to-last sentence is a non-sequitur. If I understand it correctly, you're trying to say "If $x\in X$, then by regularity $x\not\in z$," where your assumption on $z$ is just "$z$ is in $X$."

But this **isn't** enough to conclude what you want! Consider $X=\{1, \{1\}\}$ and take $z=\{1\},x=1$. Then $z\in X, x\in X$, but $x\in z$.

Comment: If I exchange the choices of $x$, $z$for, "If $x\in X, $ and for some $z$, $x\in X$ then, by the Axiom of Regularity, $x \notin_x z.$
So, $\lnot(x \in_x z),$" there would be still something missing?

Comment: @Trux "by the Axiom of Regularity, $x\not\in z$." **How are you arguing this**? Right now $x$ and $z$ are just arbitrary elements of $X$; there's no reason for $x$ to not be an element of $z$. The axiom of regularity tells us that $X$ has some element $z$ with a certain property; you need to *use* the axiom of regularity, not just assert that it solves the problem. (Also what does "for some $z$, x\in X$" mean? We already know $x\in X$ by the previous phrase.)

Comment: By contradiction. Because of, Axiom of regularity, there exists an $x$, such that, if $x \in_x z$  then $x$ is not in $X.$ But $x \in X$, so $x \notin_x z$.

Comment: You have a typo in your statement of the axiom - that should be "there exists a $z$." More to the point, note that the way you use regularity is to *introduce* an element - e.g. "By regularity, there is some $z$ such that ..." You didn't do that at all in your original answer.